# ListView for downloading files in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

It's my first application in Xamarin for Android. I want to begin with two screens:

- first (main) screen with 3 buttons: load task number 1, load task number 2, display task list,
- after pushing first or second button, the item is added to list in second screen,
- after pushing third button, second screen with tasks list is opened.

But I have problem with ListView. For example: I want add first task to ListView, back to first screen, add second task (first task should already be in list), back to first screen, push button for display second screen and two tasks should already be there.

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button addButton1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AddButton1);
        Button addButton2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AddButton2);
        Button downloadsScreen = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.DownloadsScreen);
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Downloads));

        addButton1.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            intent.PutExtra("downloads", "wartosc1");
            StartActivity(intent);
        };

        addButton2.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            intent.PutExtra("downloads", "wartosc2");
            StartActivity(intent);
        };

        downloadsScreen.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
    }
}
```

Activity with tasks:

```
public class Downloads : ListActivity
{
    Dictionary<string, Task> zadania = new Dictionary<string, Task>();
    List<string> listaZadan = new List<string>();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<string> lista = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, listaZadan);
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        var download = Intent.GetStringExtra("downloads") ?? null;
        Task zadanie = new Task();
        EncryptAndDecrypt decryption = new EncryptAndDecrypt();
        zadanie = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Task>(decryption.Decrypt(download, "haslo"));
        if (!zadania.ContainsKey(zadanie.Name))
        {
            zadania.Add(zadanie.Name, zadanie);
            listaZadan.Add(zadanie.Name);
        }
        else
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).SetMessage("Zadanie zostało już dodane do pobierania").Show();
    }
}
```

How can I fix it? Such list is a good way to display downloaded files? In the future I want add ProgressBar to each item in ListView. Please don't send links to tutorials, I saw them all. I care about information from people who deals with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I fix it? Such list is a good way to display downloaded files?

Not sure why, I have exception without any info when start a new activity which inherits from `ListActivity` like you did in your code, so I decide to use a normal `Activity` with a `ListView` control in its layout for example:

downloadslayout.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Usually when your `Downloads` inherits from `ListActivity`, we need to set `ListAdapter`, so if you don't get the same exception as mine, you will need to add such code:

```
ListAdapter = lista;
```

in the `OnCreate` of `Downloads`.

But for my method, we need firstly find this `ListView` in `DownloadsLayout` and then set its adapter, they actually are the same.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.downloadslayout);

    ListView lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview);
    ArrayAdapter<string> lista = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, listaZadan);
    lv.Adapter = lista;
}
```

> In the future I want add ProgressBar to each item in ListView.

So for your future intention, I don't think use a `ArrayAdapter` directly is a good method here, we can customize our own adapter, in the meanwhile you can customize your `ListView` cell in the `GetView` method of `Adapter`, just for example:

```
public class DownloadsAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
{
    private List<string> items = new List<string>();
    private Activity context;

    public DownloadsAdapter(Activity context, List<string> items) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public override string this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        if (view == null)
        { // otherwise create a new one
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.downloadscell, null);
        }
        var pbar = view.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressbar);

        var tv = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
        tv.Text = items[position];

        return view;
    }
}
```

And the `downloadscell.axml` is for example like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tv"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/loading" />
</LinearLayout>
```

By checking your code, you seems only want to pass strings to each item, so I used `BaseAdapter<string>` here, you can change to other types if you want. And finally in your `OnCreate`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.downloadslayout);

    ListView lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview);
    var adapter = new DownloadsAdapter(this, listaZadan);
    lv.Adapter = adapter;
}
```